How to Convert a Failed Order Back to a Cart in CraftCMS Commerce 4.x
I'm developing a custom gateway plugin for CraftCMS 4.x and I'm having trouble converting a failed order back to a cart. I have the following code that attempts to do this, but it doesn't seem to work as expected:
Basically this is a summary of the logic

Detect if the 3D Secure process failed and create a failed child transaction.
Retrieve the order associated with the transaction.
Set the order properties to revert it back to a cart.
Save the order element.

I'm not 100% sure if the order properties that I'm saving below are enough but I was hoping that the order would be converted back to a cart, allowing the user to attempt the payment again.
What happens instead is that the order remains in its failed state and is not converted back to a cart and the customer would need to add all items to the cart again.
This is the logic I've got in the webhook method:
public function processWebHook(): WebResponse
{
...
        try {
            $pinResponse = $client->request('GET', $apiUrl, [
                'query' => ['session_token' => $sessionToken],
                'auth' => [$apiKey, ''],
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]);

            $responseData = json_decode($pinResponse->getBody(), true);

            if (isset($responseData['response']['success']) && $responseData['response']['success']) {
                
                //success payment logic
            } else {
                // Payment failed
                $transaction = Commerce::getInstance()->getTransactions()->getTransactionByHash($transactionId);

                if ($transaction) {
                    $childTransaction = Commerce::getInstance()->getTransactions()->createTransaction(null, $transaction);
                    $childTransaction->orderId = $transaction->orderId;
                    $childTransaction->parentId = $transaction->id;
                    $childTransaction->gatewayId = $transaction->gatewayId;
                    $childTransaction->amount = $transaction->amount;
                    $childTransaction->currency = $transaction->currency;
                    $childTransaction->paymentAmount = $transaction->paymentAmount;
                    $childTransaction->paymentCurrency = $transaction->paymentCurrency;
                    $childTransaction->type = TransactionRecord::TYPE_PURCHASE;
                    $childTransaction->status = $responseData['response']['success'] ? TransactionRecord::STATUS_SUCCESS : TransactionRecord::STATUS_FAILED;
                    $childTransaction->message = $responseData['response']['status_message'];
                    $childTransaction->response = $responseData;
                    
                    //revert order back to cart
                    Commerce::getInstance()->getTransactions()->saveTransaction($childTransaction);
                    $order = $transaction->getOrder();
                    $redirectUrl = $order->cancelUrl;
                    $order->isCompleted = false;
                    $order->orderStatusId = null;
                    $order->dateOrdered = null;
                    $order->reference = null;
                    $order->recalculationMode = $order::RECALCULATION_MODE_ALL;
                    $order->orderCompletedEmail = null;
                    $order->returnUrl = null;
                    $order->cancelUrl = null;
                    Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($order);
              
            }
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            Craft::error('Error verifying payment: ' . $e->getMessage(), 'pin-payments');
        }
    }

    if ($redirectUrl) {
        return $response->redirect($redirectUrl);
    }

    return $response;
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
